# android browser parameters "max Response Size" and "max Multipart Response Size"

Tags: android, html, browser

there are four parameters I need to get from my android phone, Are there any way to get it.
if can not get them, any reference value I can use?  my phone screen size is 640x960.

1.maxResponseSize
(The maximum response size that the device can handle). This is the maximum size that you can downlad and vizualize in the browser. if the downloaded page is too large, the browser only can see part of the contents and the page is incomplete.

2.usableHeight (800 I guess)
(The usable height of the device browser). This is not the screen height but the broswer itself as it can be less.

3.usableWidth  (640  I guess)
(The usable width of the device browser). This is not the screen width but the broswer itself as it can be less.

4.maxMultipartResponseSize（ This is also good to know if exist）
The maximum response size that the device can handle for multipart responses with both markup and images)**